# Manipulating an array of structs in Scala Spark 3.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe whose schema looks like this

```
root
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- signals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- category string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to manipulate to filter/manipulate/transform the `signals` array of structs without exploding. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can use this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter - instead of `x`, you could use `x.category` for example, or `x.firstName`, if you still have issues, provide a small sample of data and I could show an example

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate i.e filter/manipulate/transform the array of structs without exploding. One good way could be to use UDF’s a.k.a User Defined Functions. UDF’s are used to extend the functions of the framework and re-use these functions on multiple DataFrame’s.

Transform: To add a new column pass the array to UDF & iterate on it with out exploding it.

```
@udf(returnType=StringType()) 
def udf_signals_transformation(signal):
  name = ""
  for s in signal:
    name = f"{name} {s.firstName} {s.lastName} - "
 return name

tdf = sdf.withColumn("names", udf_signals_transformation(col("signals")))
display(tdf)
```

Filter: To filter the data based on some nested condition, pass the array to UDF & iterate on it, check the condition and set a temporary flag. Finally filter the flag using spark api.

```
@udf(returnType=BooleanType()) 
def udf_signals_filter(signal):
  filter_cond = False
  for s in signal:
    if s.category == "condition":
    filter_cond = True
  return filter_cond

tdf = sdf.withColumn("tempfilter", udf_signals_filter(col("signals")))
tdf = tdf.where(col("tempfilter") == True).drop("tempfilter")
display(tdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

For transforming array-type data, consider using Spark's higher-order functions.  Below are a few examples:

```
case class Signal(category: String, firstName: String, lastName: String)

val df = Seq(
  ("c1", Seq(Signal("c1", "David", "O"), Signal("c1", "Michelle", "D"))),
  ("c2", Seq(Signal("c2", "John", "D"), Signal("c2", "Amy", "O"), Signal("c2", "Tom", "O")))
).toDF("category", "signals")
```

[`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/sql/index.html#filter):

```
df.withColumn("lastNameD", expr(
    "filter(signals, x -> x.lastName = 'D')"
  )).show(false)
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------+
// |category|signals                                    |lastNameD          |
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------+
// |c1      |[{c1, David, O}, {c1, Michelle, D}]        |[{c1, Michelle, D}]|
// |c2      |[{c2, John, D}, {c2, Amy, O}, {c2, Tom, O}]|[{c2, John, D}]    |
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

[`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/sql/index.html#transform):

```
df.withColumn("fullName", expr(
    "transform(signals, x -> concat(x.category, ': ', x.firstName, ' ', x.lastName))"
  )).show(false)
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
// |category|signals                                    |fullName                          |
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
// |c1      |[{c1, David, O}, {c1, Michelle, D}]        |[c1: David O, c1: Michelle D]     |
// |c2      |[{c2, John, D}, {c2, Amy, O}, {c2, Tom, O}]|[c2: John D, c2: Amy O, c2: Tom O]|
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

[`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/sql/index.html#aggregate):

```
df.withColumn("lastNameCount", expr("""
    aggregate(signals, cast(map() as map<string, integer>), (acc, x) -> 
      case when acc[x.lastName] is null then map_concat(acc, map(x.lastName, 1)) else
        map_concat(map_filter(acc, (k, v) -> k != x.lastName), map(x.lastName, acc[x.lastName] + 1))
      end)
  """.stripMargin
  )).show(false)
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
// |category|signals                                    |lastNameCount   |
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
// |c1      |[{c1, David, O}, {c1, Michelle, D}]        |{O -> 1, D -> 1}|
// |c2      |[{c2, John, D}, {c2, Amy, O}, {c2, Tom, O}]|{D -> 1, O -> 2}|
// +--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Note that the above examples run the higher-order functions with SQL semantic via `expr`. Spark 3+ allows expressing the functions in Scala-like syntax which, however, doesn't seem to be effective in the case of processing an array of structs.

---

Another approach is to use [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/sql/index.html#inline) along with `groupBy/agg` (or `Window/partitionBy`) to expand and process the array of structs like in the following example:

```
df.
  select(expr("inline(signals)")).
  groupBy("category","lastName").agg(count()).
  show
// +--------+--------+--------+
// |category|lastName|count(1)|
// +--------+--------+--------+
// |      c1|       D|       1|
// |      c2|       D|       1|
// |      c2|       O|       2|
// |      c1|       O|       1|
// +--------+--------+--------+
```